# Change default column values in different sitecollections from column YEAR with powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

We have SP2013. We have a lot of site collections have sites with three doc. libraries the sites contains a column YEAR, we would like to change the default column value for the column year from 2016 to 2017.

Anybody can provide a script to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: What type of column it is? single line, choice or other?

Comment: the below script in my answer worked properly with single and choice field without issue !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following script to set the default value for a specific field in Doc/List via PowerShell

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb http://yoursharepointsite
$list = $Web.Lists["listname"]
$field = $list.Fields["Year"]
$field.DefaultValue = "2017"
$field.Update()
```

**Note:** Replace the above entries [yoursharepointsite,listname] based on your value.

Comment: Thanks, just test it and it is is working. But any idea how I can make batch run script to go to all my sitecollections and doc. libraries?

Comment: There is no issue to loop to get all site collections and its doc, what I think you should specify what the doc libraries that you need to apply the above script, I don't think all your doc libraries have this field, so you should only specify the doc library name that has this field then apply the above script on it. so there is no need for loop !

Comment: By the way, I would like to ask the user who downvoted the answer, Are you tried to check if the mentioned script is working or not !?. For me, I am pretty sure it's working properly with a single text and choice field without issue! and I don't think the field type may be another type meanwhile the field type was different, this is not considered my issue the user not mentioned this in his question! so please give me one reason why you downvote it  :) !!!

Comment: Sorry did something wrong, newbie on this site. Your help is great!